# Closed expression for $\prod_{i=0}^k(1-ix)$

Tags: closed-form, products

How do I find a closed form expression for the product $\displaystyle{\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}(1-(k-i)x)}\;$?

Edit 1: @Kenta S has found a different way to index it, do you have any other ideas yet?

Comment: What are the first few examples?

Comment: It equals $\prod_{i=0}^k(1-ix)$, but I doubt there is a nice closed expression.

Comment: It is also $(-i)^k (1+i)_k$ with the [Pochhammer symbol](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28-i%29%5Em+Pochhammer%281+%2B+i%2C+m%29&assumption=%22ClashPrefs%22+-%3E+%7B%22Math%22%7D)

Answer (score 1):

We can write the product using *[Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind)* $\begin{bmatrix}k\\q\end{bmatrix}$.
\begin{align*}
\prod_{j=1}^k\left(1-jx\right)=\sum_{q=0}^k(-1)^{q}\begin{bmatrix}k+1\\k+1-q\end{bmatrix} x^q
\end{align*}
where we start with index $j=1$, since the factor with $j=0$ is $\left(1-0\cdot x\right)=1$.

> Somewhat more elaborated we can write the product using $[k]=\{1,2,\ldots,k\}$ as
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\prod_{j=1}^k\left(1-jx\right)}
> &=\sum_{S\subseteq[k]}\prod_{s\in S}\left(-sx\right)\tag{1.1}\\
> &=\sum_{q=0}^k\left(\sum_{{S\subseteq[k]}\atop{|S|=q}}(-1)^{|S|}\left(\prod_{s\in S}s\right)\right)x^q\tag{1.2}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{q=0}^k(-1)^{q}\begin{bmatrix}k+1\\k+1-q\end{bmatrix} x^q}\tag{1.3}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1.1) we write the product as sum over all subsets in $[k]$. For each index $s\in S$ we select $-sx$ from the product and $1$ otherwise.
- In (1.2) we order the summation according to the size of $S$.
- In (1.3) we use the  Stirling numbers of the first kind.

**Example: $k=3$**

Let's look at a small example $k=3$. We obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\prod_{j=1}^3(1-jx)}
&=(-1)^{|\emptyset|}\cdot 1\\
&\quad+\left((-1)^{|\{1\}|}\cdot 1+(-1)^{|\{2\}|}\cdot 2+(-1)^{|\{3\}|}\cdot 3\right)x\\
&\quad+\left(-1)^{|\{1,2\}|}\cdot 1\cdot 2+(-1)^{|\{1,3\}|}\cdot 1\cdot 3+(-1)^{|\{2,3\}|}\cdot 2\cdot 3\right)x^2\\
&\quad+\left((-1)^{|\{1,2,3\}|}\cdot 1\cdot 2\cdot 3\right) x^3\\
&=1-(1+2+3)x+(1\cdot 2+1\cdot 3+2\cdot 3)x^2-(1\cdot 2\cdot 3)x^3\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=1-6x+11x^2-6x^3}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{q=0}^3(-1)^{q}\begin{bmatrix}4\\4-q\end{bmatrix} x^q}
\end{align*}